# How do I break down files in a similar way to torrents?

Tags: python, bittorrent

I am trying to make a program that breaks down files like HTML or CSS into chunks like that of a torrent. I am completely unsure how to do this. They need to be broken down, than later reassembled in order. anybody know how to do this?

It doesn't have to be in Python, that was just my starting point.

Comment: bittorrent is best for large files.  Usually HTML and CSS files aren't that big.

Comment: Indeed, the overhead of chunking files less than a couple megabytes is likely not worth it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  You can chunk a file, but you really likely will spend more in checksumming and stitching the files back together than it's worth for the size of HTML/CSS files.

Comment: Things like jpgs and videos (Like what you'd expect to see on a website, not full movies) will also be receiving the same treatment. Even if it is relatively pointless, I would like to know.

Comment: Streaming jpegs and videos is a standard solution in such scenarios. To chunk the files, you will need the clients to be aware of how the pieces are numbered, how to verify them and how to put them together. Clients for websites are usually browsers. It might be too much to ask for browsers to implement your specific chunking strategy.

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial to "break down" files as you put it. You'll need an algorithm to disassemble them, and then to reassemble them later, presumably by a browser since you mentioned HTML and CSS. Bittorrents implements this, and additionally the ability upload and download from a distributed "swarm" of peers also interested in the same data. Without reinventing the wheel by creating your own version of bittorrent, and again assuming you want to use this data in a browser, you'll want to create a torrent of all the HTML, CSS and other files relevant to your web application, and seed that using bittorrent. Next you'll want to create a bootstrap "page" that makes use of one of the several Javascript bittorrent clients now available to download the torrent, and then load the desired pages and resources when the client completes the download.